# MudBlazor MudTextField failed to bind value

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I am trying to bind a value in `MudTextField`, but it returns the error `CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable,property or indexer`.

Is it a syntax issue which caused the error? Here's some sample code I used, but where I still failed to bind the value:

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="parent.Params.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == 'Test')?.Value"></MudTextField>
<MudTextField @bind-Value='parent.Params.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Test")?.Value'></MudTextField>
<MudTextField @bind-Value='@(parent.Params.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Test")?.Value)'></MudTextField>
```

These are the models:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Id { get; set;}
    public Child[] Params { get; set; }
}
public class Child 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I can use a different way to bind the value, but the LINQ / one-line-solution looks cleaner and elegant. How can I correctly bind the value to `MudTextField`?

Comment: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mYQxuTlLySbiFTck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do two-way binding to `null`. Let's imagine you edit the text field and value is assigned to 'null'. You have used '?.', haven't you? Does that even make sense? 'null' is not 'variable,property or indexer'. A one-liner should not be your goal...

```
@{
    Child child = parent.Params.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Name");
    
    if(child != null)
    {
        <MudTextField @bind-Value=@child.Value></MudTextField>
    }
}

@code {
    Parent parent = new();

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        parent.Params = new Child[] { new Child() };
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: ya this is actually my current solution, just wondering whether the one-liner is achievable.... 

'null' is not 'variable,property or indexer' <<< thanks for the explanation, guess i will stick with my current solution.